# ruby parameter expansion like in bash

Tags: ruby

i am am bashist  an i to set a default value if var is not set

ruby code , settings are read from a yaml file

```
:username => settings[:username],
:password => settings[:password],
:host => settings[:dns_server],
:ssl_opts => {:verify => true }
```

I want to implement a yaml entry somthing like `ssl_verify:` , so that if not set , `true` is the default .

This would look like,

in bash that would look like

```
ssl_opts=${ssl_verify:-true}
```

how to do this in ruby?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do nice one-liners in ruby, variable = condition ? true : false

```
ssl_opts = ssl_verify.nil? ? true : ssl_verify
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the yaml is parsed and is a Ruby hash, there are a few ways:

```
verify = yaml[:ssl_opts][:verify] || true
```

You can access the hash keys as such. The `||` will return the value to the right if the expression to the left evaluates to `nil`. If the `ssl_opts` key was missing this would raise an error.

```
verify = yaml.dig(:ssl_options, :verify) || true
```

`#dig` takes any number of keys and returns the value or `nil` if any of the keys are missing. If the `ssl_options` key was missing this would not raise an error.

```
verify = yaml.fetch(:ssl_opts).fetch(:verify, true)
```

`#fetch` will raise if the key does not exist, the optional second argument is a default if the key does not exist.

Comment: With the first two, it's impossible to set the value to `false` in the yaml. `false || true` will always be true.

Comment: @KimmoLehto Good catch. And worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with a single-layer structure is pretty easy:

```
DEFAULTS = {
  ssl_opts_verify: true
}

options = DEFAULTS.merge(settings)
```

Where you can just use `merge` to build on the defaults. For a multi-layer structure you need a `deep_merge` type tool.